# Use an image instead of text (script type="text/javascript")

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, widget

I have some code provided by the vendor:

```
<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)">FREE Puppies</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd"></script>
```

I want to replace the `FREE Puppies` text with an image.  The vendor says it can't be done, but I disagree.  I've tried several different things but nothing seems to work quite right.  I'd really appreciate some help.  I know I'm just missing something small.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you implementing the link yourself or is the link generated by a script? You can just replace the text with an image tag `<a><img></a>`. If it's generated by a script you'd have to modify the script. It's not clear what the `type` attribute of the `script` element has to do with your question, if at all.

Comment: what are some of the `several different things` you've tried?

Comment: Here is the thing I thought most likely to work.  BTW, this is in a TEXT box in a Wordpress Widget.  I put that in the tags, but not my question! 

`<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/ccdhppwcbfbkhndfgtrvsdrgtkxwfvnx" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)"> <img src="http://www.harmonyrescue.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Opt_in_Ribbon_Chall‌​‌​enges.png" ></a><script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/ccdhppwcbfbkhndfgtrvsdrgtkxwfvn‌​‌​x"></script>` It does show the image, but the on_click doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Only replacing the text with an image is not going to work, because the embedded script looks for the `href` attribute of the clicked element (`event.target`). In the case of an image inside a link tag, the target element is the image, and does not have an `href` attribute.

To solve that, you can catch the event on any image that is inside these links, block it, and simulate a click on the parent link.

**Demo *not using jQuery***

```js
var sh_lead_images = document.querySelectorAll('.sh_lead_button img');

for(var i=0; i<sh_lead_images.length; i++)
{
    sh_lead_images[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        this.parentNode.click();
    });
}
```

```html
<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)">
  <img src="http://www.truthunity.net/sites/all/content/graphics/ministry-click-me-button.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd"></script>
```

**Demo *using jQuery***

```js
$('.sh_lead_button img').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().click();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)">
  <img src="http://www.truthunity.net/sites/all/content/graphics/ministry-click-me-button.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd"></script>
```

Comment: these look great, but when I attempt to use the same code in the Wordpress widget it doesn't work properly.  Any ideas?  thanks!

Comment: @Violett Did you use it this way : [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/NSJ85jzR) ? If you did and it does not work, open your Javascript console (press F12), are there any red error messages? If there are, paste them here.

Comment: Thanks @blex!  That solved the problem.  I've been dinking around with this for a few days and you solved it!

Comment: @Violett Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the source html, you should can easily place an image tag.

```
<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)">
    <img src="wherever-you-have-your-image.png">
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/sfrnrskrvhcncwvnrtwwvhxvzkrvzhsd"></script>
```

Regards,

F.

Comment: Thanks F. Here is what I had tried:

`<a class="sh_lead_button" href="https://107617.17hats.com/p#/lcf/ccdhppwcbfbkhndfgtrvsdrgtkxwfvnx" onclick="shLeadFormPopup.openForm(event)"> <img src="http://www.harmonyrescue.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Opt_in_Ribbon_Chall‌​enges.png" /></a><script type="text/javascript" src="https://107617.17hats.com/embed/lead/script/ccdhppwcbfbkhndfgtrvsdrgtkxwfvn‌​x"></script>`

But it didn't work.  It does show the image, but the on_click doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I just caught the extra '/' at the end of my image source and removed it.  Still not working...

Comment: If you have an link element, that redirects to a page, you should first prevent the browser to go that page, if you are trying to run the code inside shLeadFormPopup.openForm method.

Maybe you need to preventDefault the browser to go that page, do whatever you need, and then redirect to the page you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can place and image tag into an a tag. Like this:

```
<a class="sh_lead_button" href="http://www.google.es" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7c4c20b9134504e04754d751aa7f90c1?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" >
</a>
```

There's no mention on the original question about an embedded script.

Comment: _"There's no mention on the original question about an embedded script."_ Yes there is, look at his code, there is a `<script>` tag.

Comment: But there's no code inside it, and the original question do not talk about it. It's just asking for replacing an text node by a image, so my answer it works in that context.

Anyway, you may get any element of the page just playing around with DOM.